# Export User Info into CSV - Additional Column

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm using the 'Export Users to CSV' a plugin for wordpress. By default, The plugin only extracts wp_users and wp_usermeta

I have been wanting to add post_title column from wp_posts. I was able to pull out the 'post_title' into the CSV file BUT it's not placed correctly in its respective row.

Please see my edited code and original code

Orignal version:

```
global $wpdb;
$data_keys = array(
    'ID', 'user_login', 'user_pass',
    'user_nicename', 'user_email', 'user_url',
    'user_registered', 'user_activation_key', 'user_status',
    'display_name'
);
$meta_keys = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT distinct(meta_key) FROM $wpdb->usermeta" );
$meta_keys = wp_list_pluck( $meta_keys, 'meta_key' );
$fields = array_merge( $data_keys, $meta_keys);

$headers = array();
foreach ( $fields as $key => $field ) {
    if ( in_array( $field, $exclude_data ) )
        unset( $fields[$key] );
    else
        $headers[] = '"' . strtolower( $field ) . '"';
}
echo implode( ',', $headers ) . "\n";

foreach ( $users as $user ) {
    $data = array();
    foreach ( $fields as $field ) {
        $value = isset( $user->{$field} ) ? $user->{$field} : '';
        $value = is_array( $value ) ? serialize( $value ) : $value;
        $data[] = '"' . str_replace( '"', '""', $value ) . '"';
    }
    echo implode( ',', $data ) . "\n";
}
```

Edited version

```
global $wpdb;

$data_keys = array(
    'ID', 'user_login', 'user_pass',
    'user_nicename', 'user_email', 'user_url',
    'user_registered', 'user_activation_key', 'user_status',
    'display_name'
);
$meta_keys = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT distinct(meta_key) FROM $wpdb->usermeta" );
$meta_keys = wp_list_pluck( $meta_keys, 'meta_key' );
$post_keys = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT distinct(post_title) FROM $wpdb->posts" );
$post_keys = wp_list_pluck( $post_keys, 'post_title' );
$fields = array_merge( $data_keys, $meta_keys, $post_keys);

$headers = array();
foreach ( $fields as $key => $field ) {
    if ( in_array( $field, $exclude_data ) )
        unset( $fields[$key] );
    else
        $headers[] = '"' . strtolower( $field ) . '"';
}
echo implode( ',', $headers ) . "\n";

foreach ( $users as $user ) {
    $data = array();
    foreach ( $fields as $field ) {
        $value = isset( $user->{$field} ) ? $user->{$field} : '';
        $value = is_array( $value ) ? serialize( $value ) : $value;
        $data[] = '"' . str_replace( '"', '""', $value ) . '"';
    }
    echo implode( ',', $data ) . "\n";
}
```

I hope my explanation is not confusing. Cheers!

Here's an image to explain it better :

https://www.dropbox.com/s/xijkb4fp16atcx3/question-jpeg.jpg?dl=0

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you are using the list of titles as columns, since `wp_list_pluck` doesn't retain the column name `post_title`.

The approach would be different if you want to use just one title post per user, or you want more, especially since the name for the column will change.
Assuming you want them all, we can create a simple approach that you can improve.

For example, I would say.

First, remove these two lines

```
$post_keys = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT distinct(post_title) FROM $wpdb->posts" );
$post_keys = wp_list_pluck( $post_keys, 'post_title' );
```

and change `$fields = array_merge( $data_keys, $meta_keys, $post_keys);`by `$fields = array_merge( $data_keys, $meta_keys, $post_keys);`

Then, before

```
 echo implode( ',', $data ) . "\n";
```

you add

```
$post_keys = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT distinct(post_title) FROM $wpdb->posts  WHERE (post_type LIKE 'page' OR post_type LIKE 'post') and post_status LIKE 'publish' AND post_author = ". $user->ID );
$post_titles = wp_list_pluck( $post_keys, 'post_title');
$data =array_merge ($data, $post_titles);
```

With this, the column headers for the post titles wont be set, we can improve it to set it if you need it, but you should have already a column per every post title

Comment: Actually i'm wrong, your code did pullout the post titles, but they aren't arranged as per user. the post titles came out in a large long horizontal cells: please check this https://www.dropbox.com/s/xijkb4fp16atcx3/question-jpeg.jpg?dl=0 at the end of the image, that's the results layout that i want

Comment: remove the `"` after `FROM $wpdb->posts`

Comment: also change `$fields = array_merge( $data_keys, $meta_keys, $post_keys);` by `$fields = array_merge( $data_keys, $meta_keys);`

Comment: and also remove last ." after `post_author = ". $user->ID`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95197/discussion-between-jeremi-liwanag-and-carlos-robles).